# Can you MST connect monitors using " 'displayPort' to 'mini displayPort' " cables only?

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport, mini-displayport, daisychaining, mst

Can I **MST connect** multiple monitors using `mini DP -> DP` cables only? (*I'm confused on whether I might need a `DP -> DP` cable between the monitors?*)

[image: This]

Image of `mini DP -> DP` cable

Answer (score 2):

They are electrically the same -so as long as you have a DP out and a DP in that correspond to either end of the cable, it should work. From memory, the DP outs were full sized on the dell monitor I had which did MST, and the mini DP input worked identically to the standard DP out.

Comment: That's what I thought too, mind taking a look at my edit. I can't for the live of me figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: Resolution/refresh rate? My Dell monitor stated it would do 4k30 at MST. The video out also needs to support MST I think

Comment: Does it matter which end is stuck into which device (by device I mean laptop or monitor)?

Comment: Nope. It does not

Answer (score 2):

[According to NotebookCheck](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-HD-Graphics-5500.125586.0.html), the Intel® HD Graphics 5500 integrated GPU supports only DisplayPort 1.2. [DisplayPort 1.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#1.2) can support a *single 4K screen* (up to 75 Hz) at Y′C<sub>B</sub>C<sub>R</sub> 4:4:4 (full 24 bit RGB). With reduced refresh rate and/or color subsampling, more is possible of course, but both ends of the connection would need to support it.

Another limiting factor is what the MST hub in the first display decides to do. It may simply “disconnect” the second display because the first display requires all DP streams for itself.

Your best bet to have both displays work with your laptop is to use a USB graphics solution (DisplayLink). It comes with limitations of course.

Comment: **One question:** Do you think an adapter with two DP outputs and one DP input might solve the problem too?

Comment: You are thinking about these [products](https://www.displaylink.com/products/find?cat=3&vid_dp=1), right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. // A separate MST hub cannot help either. The DisplayPort output on your laptop simply does not have the required bandwidth. There is no way to change that.